# Firebase Retrieving Data is not working for my web

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am learning Firebase. I am trying to read data from Firebase but function is not triggered. Below is my javascript code.
**getCount()**

```
var exam = localStorage.EXAM;
var subject = localStorage.SUBJECT;
var ref = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL);
var TotQuestion = ref.child(exam).child(subject).child("TotQuestion");
TotQuestion.on("value", function(snapshot) 
{
    if(snapshot.child("count").val() != null) 
    {
      var count = snapshot.child("count").val();
        if(count == null)
          {
            localStorage.setItem("COUNT", "0");
            window.location.href="QAdd.html";
          }else{
            localStorage.setItem("COUNT", count);
            window.location.href="QAdd.html";
          }
    }   


},function (errorObject) {
  console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
});
```

I am getting exam and subject from localStorage from previous screen.I debug the application but control is not entering in function **function(snapshot)** 
this script is triggered on button click from html form. Please help.
Thanks
Deepak

updating the Question:

I have two function. 
**myFunction**

```
if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") 
            {
                localStorage.setItem("SUBJECT", subject);
                getCount();


            } else 
            {
                    document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support Web Storage...";
            }
```

In above code I am calling getCount() function. where I am accessing Firebase and getting count. program fails on setting null value to innerHTML.
document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = localStorage.COUNT;
The reason is system not going in Firebase call and setting innerHTML as null.

Now I am getting below error.

```
FIREBASE WARNING: Exception was thrown by user callback. TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
at file:///D:/Firebase%20Web/Sub.html:84:55
at c (https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.4.2/firebase.js:242:58)
at https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.4.2/firebase.js:203:710
at gc (https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.4.2/firebase.js:52:165)
at cc (https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.4.2/firebase.js:30:216)
at dc (https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.4.2/firebase.js:29:1259)
at Ji.h.Kb (https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.4.2/firebase.js:222:287)
at Rh.h.Ld (https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.4.2/firebase.js:189:251)
at Fh.Ld (https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.4.2/firebase.js:179:364)
at kh.nc (https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.4.2/firebase.js:177:280)
```

and

```
Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.
```

This is solved now. below is the correct code.

**myFunction**

```
if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") 
                {
                    localStorage.setItem("SUBJECT", subject);
                    getCount();


                } else 
                {
                        document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support Web Storage...";
                }


function getCount(){
                var exam = localStorage.EXAM;
                var subject = localStorage.SUBJECT;
                var ref = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL);
                var TotQuestion = ref.child(exam).child(subject).child("TotQuestion").child("count");
                TotQuestion.once("value",function(snapshot){
                        if(snapshot.val() != null) 
                        {
                                var count = snapshot.val();
                                if(count == null)
                                    {
                                        localStorage.setItem("COUNT", "0");
                                        window.location.href="QAdd.html";
                                    }else{
                                        localStorage.setItem("COUNT", count);
                                        window.location.href="QAdd.html";
                                    }

                        }   


                },function (errorObject){
                        console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
                            });
        }
```

This successfully transfer control to QAdd.html with correct value.

Comment: The code by itself looks fine, so it's likely something else that causes the problem. Did you check the JavaScript console for error? If there are no errors showing, can you set up a minimal jsfiddle/jsbin that reproduces the problem?

Comment: console showing nothing. snapshot & errorObject showing <not available> while debugging. As soon as control reaches to TotQuestion.on("value", function(snapshot) , it jump to next statement. It didn't enter to Firebase data read.

Comment: You will never be able to step into that call, since it's an asynchronous callback. But if you set a breakpoint on (for example) `if(snapshot.child("count").val() != null)` does the debugger break there?

Comment: I think you got it right. I put the break point in if(snapshot.child("count").val() != null) statement, control does come to this statement but after little late. it execute the other UI statement where I was accessing localStorage.setItem("COUNT", count). it fails there.

Comment: What does it do? Throw an error? Transition to `QAdd.html`?

Comment: I have updated the code a little bit now I am getting error. I have updated my question with details and error.

Comment: I put break point on var exam = localStorage.EXAM; and if(snapshot.val() != null) . system first goes to var exam = localStorage.EXAM; and execute complete script and second time it start with if(snapshot.val() != null) and control shifted to QAdd.html page.

Comment: That last warning is harmless. The one before looks like a real issue. If you look on line 84 of `Sub.html` you should find the cause.

Comment: Thanks..your guidance help a lot. I finally have working code now. Thanks again. I am updating correct code in question.

Comment: Please post it as an answer with an explanation of the change you had to make. Self-answering is completely acceptable here on Stack Overflow and may be useful to future visitors.